No module named 'vtkmodules.vtkCommonCore'
I worked before with pyvista and it was perfectly working until now.
I try to run a simple code and does not work.
The error is:

from . import _vtk_core
from vtkmodules.vtkCommonCore import vtkVersion
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'vtkmodules.vtkCommonCore'

import pyvista as pv

sphere = pv.Sphere(radius=1.0, center=(0, 0, 0))

plotter = pv.Plotter()

plotter.add_mesh(sphere, color="skyblue", show_edges=True)

plotter.view_isometric()

plotter.show()


Python environments as a rule don't break by themselves. Did you change something? Did you update/install something? Is this a new Python environment? Is VTK installed? If it is, what version of PyVista and VTK do you have? [Edit]ing your question with the output of pv.Report() would help a lot.
